Can a metamath identifier be reused across scopes?
I am writing a metamath verifier in OCaml as a learning exercise.
I am mostly working off of their book and some other things like this presentation.
So far I've worked on this without consulting the source code of existing verifiers.
Anyway, one thing that confuses me from the description of Metamath from the book is the notion of an active variable.
Here's an excerpt from page 125 (143 by pdf numbering)

Each math symbol (including constant and variable) must be a previously declared constant or variable. (In addition, each math symbol must be active, which will be covered when we discuss scoping statements in section 4.2.8)

The scoping statements in metamath are ${ and $}.
I had been treating these things like { and } in C-like languages, namely that they create an entirely new namespace in which local bindings can live. I was treating $e, $f, $d, $v notions as bound to a scope and $c, and $p as independent of the scope stack.
That passage, however, suggests that my strategy doesn't actually conform to the semantics of Metamath and that identifiers that have gone out of scope are nonetheless permanently consumed and cannot be reused.

This is the representation below I was using for my metamath kernel. I'm writing this thing in a mostly imperative style and setting the kernel up in such a way that it can be fed one symbol at a time.
type scope = {
        variables : (string, int) Hashtbl.t; (* map from variables to the line where they were defined *)
        distinctions : (string, string) Hashtbl.t; (* bimap *)
        f_statements : (string, judgment) Hashtbl.t; (* map f to a typing judgment *)
        e_statements : (string, string list) Hashtbl.t; (* map e to whatever *)
}

type t = {
        (* needed for rules like $e, $f, $a, $p which take an identifier before the $x symbol *)
    mutable prev_token : string;
    (* the current label for an $e, $f, $a, $p rule *)
        mutable current_label : string;
        (* mutable buffer storing the content of the current rule to be processed,
           in reverse order because I'm using linked lists for everything instead of dynamic arrays. *)
        mutable current_buffer : string list;
        (* stack of scopes currently in effect *)
        mutable scope_stack : scope list;
        mutable in_comment : commentState;
        mutable state : state;
        mutable constants : (string, int) Hashtbl.t;
}


When developing your code, I would use set.mm as a unit test (or maybe more accurately an integration test).  I think you will find quickly by looking in set.mm how at least in practice things are done (like which things are reference in scope only, which are referenced out of scope and which only go in the top scope).

An interesting link to test a new verifier is metamath-test. It's a collection of several databases, including some error cases. Other error cases can be found in the verifiers's own test suites.

As I understand it, variables can be reused, which means they can be active, then be deactivated via $}, and later be activated again. So for example the following file will be accepted:
${
  $v x y $.
  $( ... $)
$}

$v x y $.
${
  $( ... $)
$}

As a side note, $c statements avoid this issue as they can only appear in the top scope, so there is no difference whether you treat it like $v or like $a.
This is also the de-facto behavior of most verifiers, including metamath.exe.

In set.mm, you can check for vx.wal, vx.cv, vx.tru. Above each of those is a $v x $. statement which locally declares x as a variable, while the top-level declaration is before statement vx. So just like in Trebor's example, x is declared several times locally, and then later again globally.

Thank you. Do you know whether there's any meaningful distinction between a deactivated variable and one that does not exist?

@GregNisbet My understanding is there is no distinction.  If it is out of scope, it just doesn’t exist (in that it can’t be referenced).
